# Tax Calculation

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, tax, shipping-tax

I want to set tax as per bellow.

```
Product cost + shipping cost + 11% (packing and handling charges) = subtotal.

Subtotal + VAT (5% ON SUBTOTAL) = Grand total.
```

is it possible in magento. if possible than please let me know how can i achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

By default magento is calculating the tax based on the subtotal. If you want to check your current values or change them go to:

Go to System > Configuration > Sales > Tax

Additionally you can take a look here for a very nice tutorial: http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/managing-taxes

Also:

> Tax Calculation Method Based On - from this drop-down menu you can select whether the tax should be calculated per product, per row or whether the total sum should be used. You can choose between Total, Unit Price and Row Total. The default is Total which means that the tax will be based on the whole sum of all the ordered products. If you select Unit Price the tax will be calculated separately based on the price of each individual product. If you select Row Total the tax will be calculated separately for each row in the cart. Each ordered product is represented in a separate row in the cart and the row includes the quantity too. So one row may include several units of the same product; this differentiates the Row Total option and the Unit Price option (where if there are several units of the same product tax is calculated per unit).

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/system-tax-settings